# При создании приложения у меня возникла проблема с EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, focus

При открытии новой активности с `EditText` фокус автоматически устанавливается на первый `EditText`. Мне нужно сделать, чтобы фокус устанавливался только при нажатии на соответствующий `EditText`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Установите в родительском макете такой тег:

```
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/how-to-stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup-in-android) есть подобное обсуждение.

**P.S.** При публикации новых вопросов, прикладывайте пожалуйста хоть какой-то код. Вот например у вас проблемы с полем для ввода, поэтому не помешало бы приложить код xml вашей разметки.

Comment: Спасибо, в будущем учту)

Comment: Если ответ решает вашу проблему, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него :)

Comment: Странно, я на нее нажал уже